# Can't stop a Runnable once I've passed it to Swing's invokeAndWait within a different thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, future, executorservice

I have a class with a fixed thread pool which I use to run a procedure multiple times. Part of the procedure involves creating a `Runnable` that gets passed to `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` in order to update my Swing GUI.

I want to be able to pre-empt any running procedure when I issue a request to run the procedure again. To this end, I keep the `Future` from the last `submit()` call so I can `cancel()` it. I also keep the last `Runnable` so I can set a flag on it which tells it to do nothing when `run()`, since it may have been passed to the AWT event thread and thus I can't stop it by cancelling my `Future`.

However, no matter what I do, the `Runnable` gets executed anyway. Here is a stripped-down example:

```
class Procedure {
    private AtomicReference<Updater> updater;
    private AtomicReference<Future<?>> currProcedure;
    private ExecutorService threadPool;
    private Runnable theProcedure;

    public Procedure() {
        updater = new AtomicReference<Updater>();
        currProcedure = new AtomicReference<Future<?>>();
        threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        theProcedure = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                doProcedure();
            }
        };
    }
    private void doProcedure() {
        // a bunch of stuff
        updater.set(new Updater());
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(updater.get());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException ex) {

        }
        // some more stuff
    }
    public void execute() {
        try {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (null != currProcedure.get()) {
                    currProcedure.get().cancel(true);
                }
                if (null != updater.get()) {
                    updater.get().cancel();
                }
            }
            currProcedure.set(threadPool.submit(theProcedure));
        } catch (RejectedExecutionException ex) {

        }
    }
}

class Updater implements Runnable {
    private AtomicBoolean cancelled;

    public Updater() {
        cancelled = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    }
    public void cancel() {
        cancelled.set(true);
    }
    public void run() {
        if (cancelled.get()) {
            return;
        }
        // do the GUI update
    }
}
```

It would get used like so:

```
Procedure p = new Procedure();
p.execute();
p.execute();
```

In reality, I am calling `Procedure.execute()` from the AWT event thread, so I think that may have something to do with it; other than that, I have no idea what I am doing wrong or how I can achieve my goal. Any help?

*Edit*: I have also tried to `cancel()` my `Updater` off of the AWT event thread, but no luck anyway:

```
if (null != currProcedure.get()) {
    currProcedure.get().cancel(true);
}
if (null != updater.get()) {
    threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            updater.get().cancel();
        }
    });
}
```

*Edit 2*: My logging statements seem to imply that I successfully interrupt the `updater` (I get a `java.lang.InterruptedException`) but the `run()` executes anyway (and `cancelled.get()` is still `false` at the end of it). Why wouldn't `cancel(true)` stop the execution of the `updater`?

Comment: As you once passed to the Event Queue, the `Runnable` will be executed, but I assume you mean it's not seeing the cancelled state?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Precisely. I had a hard time expressing it succinctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is broken in several ways. You seem to expect `AtomicReference` to fix your race conditions magically but all it provides is, as the name suggest, an *atomic* access to a reference. If you access that object multiple times you have multiple accesses each of them being atomic but together still not being thread safe.

First example:

```
updater.set(new Updater());
try {
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(updater.get());
} catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException ex) {
}
```

Both, the `set` and the following `get` calls are atomic, but who says that the reference you will receive on `get` is still the one you have `set` previously? You might, for example, receive an even newer `Updater` instance which is scheduled by another thread leading to the situation that one `Updater` is never sent to the EDT but the other twice.

Second example:

```
if (null != currProcedure.get()) {
    currProcedure.get().cancel(true);
}
if (null != updater.get()) {
    updater.get().cancel();
}
```

Same error two times. You are checking the result of `AtomicReference.get()` against `null` but being non-`null` on that invocation, who says that it is still non-`null` on the *next* invocation? You have that code in a `synchronized` block but since the same variables are accessed by other threads, e.g. from within `doProcedure()` without synchronization, it does not provide any protection. Maybe you never reset the reference to `null` (which would be another error) so it’s no problem here but it clearly shows a misunderstanding of how to use `AtomicReference`s.

---

Further, you say you are using it like this:

```
Procedure p = new Procedure();
p.execute();
p.execute();
```

So you are invoking `execute` right one after another and these execute methods try to cancel whatever they find in `updater` *immediately* but at this time the background is likely executing your “bunch of stuff” and has not managed to set its `updater` (as [Harald has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23411949/2711488)). So both `execute` calls might see `null` or a very outdated `Updater` instance and *afterwards* the background thread sets the first `Updater` and later on the second `Updater`, none of them being ever canceled. Note that the interruption of the background thread ends the *waiting* part of `invokeAndWait` but does not cancel the *execution* of the provided runnable.

---

Since you are using `AtomicReference` you should start really using it. The atomic updates are the key feature to implement the intended logic, e.g.:

```
Updater newUpdater=new Updater();
Updater old=updater.getAndSet(newUpdater);
if(old!=null) old.cancel();
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(newUpdater);
```

By reading the old updater and setting the new atomically you ensure that each new `Updater` is paired with the potential cancellation of an old one. And by keeping the values in local variables instead of reading them multiple times you ensure that there can be no in-between update changing the references. This works even with multiple background threads and does not need additional `synchronized` blocks.

The call to schedule the `Updater` has been changed to `invokeLater`, because in the case of a single threaded executor waiting for the completion of the `Updater` would imply that the thread never comes to set the new `Updater` and canceling the old one.

Note that the `Updater` itself should set the `updater` reference to `null` on completion. There is no point in canceling an `Updater` which has already completed but since the `updater` reference is a shared reference which might exist far longer than the (intended) life time of the `Updater` it should be cleared so it can be garbage collected immediately instead of lying around until the next `Updater` is set.

Comment: Thanks for all of the explanation. I definitely was misunderstanding how to use an `AtomicReference`.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like the problem is in line

```
// a bunch of stuff
```

While the bunch of stuff is executed, we have the following situation

1. `currProcedure` contains the Nth run of `theProcedure`, while
2. `updater` only contains the (N-1)st instance of `Updater`.

Consequently your two `cancel` calls in the `synchronized(true)` block do not target a matching pair of items. In fact, the (N-1)st `Updater` is canceled, but that one is long done. On the other hand the "bunch of stuff" likely does not care about the `cancel(true)` called on the `Future`, so once its done, the lines after the "bunch of stuff" are run undeterred and schedule the next `Updater`.

To solve the situation, the following may help. After the "bunch of stuff", put the following code:

```
synchronized(this) {
  if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    // copy the lines after "a bunch of stuff here to schedule the updater
  }
}
```

And within `execute()` you don't need to bother with canceling the `Updater`. It does not need any cancelation feature.

The two `synchronized` blocks you now have put a proper ordering into events. Either a fresh `execute()` makes it into the synchronized block first. Then it can preempt a running `doProcedure` from scheduling an `Updater`, or the `doProcedure` makes it into synchronized first. Well, then the `Updater` deserves to run, doesn't it? There has to be a point of no return.

I am assuming here that `cancel(true)` on the `Future` ends up as an `.interrupt()` on the underlying thread (not sure currently, look it up). If not, you surely find a way to interrupt the `doProcedure` thread somehow.

Comment: You are correct about what `cancel(true)` does. Thanks, I incorporated a check like that.